# Angular usando el servicio httpclient no puede mandar el formulario al nodemailer

Tags: angular, nodemailer

Cuando hago submit al formulario en consola recibo este error:

```
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /sendFormData</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

El error dice que no encuentra el archivo sendFormData por POST no?.

Este es el codigo del backend ( es para mandar emails con angular y nodemailer).

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const xoauth2 = require("xoauth2");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Accept, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));

app.post('/sendFormData', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body, 'data of form');
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    secure: 'true',
    port: '465',
    auth: {
      user: 'hjkhjkhjk@gmail.com', // must be Gmail
      pass: 'password'
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'angularform@gmail.com',
    to: 'southcode2019@gmail.com', // must be Gmail
    cc:`${req.body.name} <${req.body.email}>`,
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    html: `
            <table style="width: 100%; border: none">
              <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #000; color: #fff;">
                  <th style="padding: 10px 0">Name</th>
                  <th style="padding: 10px 0">E-mail</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th style="text-align: center">${req.body.name}</th>
                  <td style="text-align: center">${req.body.email}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          `
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'successfuly sent!'
      })
    }
  });

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server run!!!");
});
```

sendemailservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Iinfo } from '../interface/info.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SendemailserviceService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  sendEmail(obj): Observable<Iinfo> {
  return this.http.post<Iinfo>('http://localhost:4200/sendFormData', obj)
}
}
```

No consigo hacer llegar los datos del objeto con los campos del formulario usando el servicio anterior.

​

Answer (score 0):

Tu api en express senala que se inicia en el puerto `3000`

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server run!!!");
});
```

Asi que tu url en angular debe ser asi:

```
sendEmail(obj): Observable<Iinfo> {
  return this.http.post<Iinfo>('http://localhost:3000/sendFormData', obj)
}
```

Nota que cambie el puerto `4200` por el `3000`

Comment: Eso no soluciona el problema angular no ve el archivo de nodemailer y cuando he usado php tampoco puede ver el archivo de php (en assets). siempre tengo el error 404 not found!

Comment: A que te refieres que no ve el archivo php? No veo ningun codigo php en tu pregunta.